# Combo Chart from Google Charts Library

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to use ComboCharts .

In its `options` variable, it sets a value `5` against `series` in example [Here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart). What does this 5 mean ?

```
 var options = {
    title : 'Monthly Coffee Production by Country',
    vAxis: {title: "Cups"},
    hAxis: {title: "Month"},
    seriesType: "bars",
      series: {5: {type: "line"}}
  };
```

**Edit:** I now realize that this `5` is the value types per value on vAxis

While I experimented, changing `5` to `0,1,2,3 or 4.` It only changed the position of the line.
How is it related to position of line in the chart ?

Answer (score 1):

The number there is the zero based index of the series in your data that you are changing the properties of.  The `seriesType: "bars"` part in you options says all of your series will default to being rendered as bars.

When you specifically call out a series like that you are overriding the defaults.  In this case you were saying that column 5 should be rendered as a line.

Take a look at this example to see the relationship between the series and the data.

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ["X", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C5"],
        ["A", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        ["B", 2, 5, 1, 7, 9],
        ["C", 6, 2, 4, 1, 8],
        ["D", 7, 1, 2, 3, 6]
    ]);


    var options = {
        seriesType: "bars",
        series: {
            // Make the first column (C1) a blue bar (bar because it is the default)
            0: {
                color: "blue"
            },
            // Make the fourth column (C4) a green line (line because we overrode the default)
            3: {
                type: "line",
                color: "green"
            }
        }
    };
    
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById("chart"));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```